# Is it possible to reduce range of an RF receiver or transmitter for LED Strip lights?

Tags: led, rf, antenna, led-strip, remote

Background:

I recently purchased a couple of strip led lights with remote. These were installed in different rooms.

Problem:

The remote seems to be RF and not IR, thus all the lights in various rooms turn on/off together. This is pretty annoying at the least.

<s>Learned from [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256539/is-it-possible-to-control-distance-of-rf-transmitter) that reducing transmitter range may not be possible.</s>  
**<==This is what finally worked, hence edited the title!!**

I wonder if there is any possibility to reduce the range of receiver (picture attached.)

FYI, the receiver is also the power supply.

I cut off the green circled coil and still this light works from the remote in other room.
What is the plate in the red circle?

Edit 1:

1. I tried wrapping the receiver/power supply in aluminum  foil (Like all around except the leaving space for prongs.) It surprisingly had no impact. This still puzzles me.
2. I have 3 remotes and 3 of these lights. One remote can control all.

Edit 2:

1. Adding two other pics of that RED thingy
2. Name on the Power supply is CNSUNWAY Lighting

**Edit 3:
Found something that worked for me. Will post the answer below.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you buy 1 remote with two led strips? Can you buy a remote without a corresponding led strip? The remotes and strips may be paired in some way. Where did you get them from,  who is the manufacturer?

Comment: Regardless, one might not want some Alibaba-certified radio sending all over one's home.

Comment: Reducing the range of a receiver is like saying "reducing the range of a photodiode" - it just doesn't make sense. Reducing the sensitivity makes sense because receivers don't have a range.

Comment: *Is it possible to reduce range of RF receiver?* Wrap it in aluminium foil and the range should be decreased to almost **zero**. That might not be a good idea due to heat-buildup. If this product does not have some kind of pairing procedure to couple the LEDs to the remote that would be very odd. If your neighbours bought the same unit then you could control each other's LEDs.

Comment: use adhesive backed foil and heat build-up will be minimised.

Comment: Many RF-controlled lights allow you to change the code for multiple lights to coexist, check if your LED strip can do that.

Comment: Maybes: Partial metallic shielding. | Reduce antenna effectiveness | Add a resistor across antenna feed point to ground. | If possible add a shield on the non TX side - may or may not be constant.

Comment: Edited the original to add more info regarding my failed experiment with Aluminum foil and that I have 3 remotes. That foil thing not working is perplexing. Also, what is that thing in RED circle?

Comment: @DevL: that thing in the red circle could be just a piece of shielding material, or it could be a planar antenna of some sort. Does it have some PCB traces on it? The radioes probably have AGC, and the RX AGC range would be pretty broad, that's how the range of distances covered is achieved. The box working in a ball of tinfoil is indeed somewhat impressive :-) And using tin foil to configure a limit on distance is kind of futile. If you have several of these remotes at home, you should use a model that uses unique codes to match/bind a transmitter to a particular receiver.

Comment: No way to change the channel or code, I opened up both the remote and receiver. At least, not that could see..... @frr and others, added additional pics for that RED thingy..... At this point, I'm more curious - Why this receiver does not. have any visible antenna and still be able to work inside a foil.

Comment: The receiver is presumably on the vertically mounted sub board.  Aluminum foil is a terrible shielding material; the joints won't have electrical intregrity due to the oxide which forms in air, and the wires in provide a path.  You'd have more luck working the transmitter to have a resistor instead of an antenna.  But really, these products just aren't suited to your needs.

Comment: I wonder if you could somehow shield around most of the transmitter with some type of metal tube so that it becomes directional.

Answer (score 1):

Rednecky Solution that worked:

Thanks for chiming in @mhaselup @Lundin @Bimperlrekkie @比尔盖子 @Russell McMahon @frr @Chris Stratton @Justin

For others looking for similar problem, here is what worked for me.
Issue: 3 LED Strip lights in different rooms, change together even if you want to control a single one.
Ideally, buy the IR lights, so you don't face this issue.

What did not work: Changes in Power Supply/Receiver did not work. Ignore my misdirection towards that plate and antenna.

What worked (takes 15 mins):

1. Open up the remote - Remove battery, Peel top layer and then open up 4 tiny screws. Pull the PCB out, gently.
2. Scrape off the printed connection to antenna, blue circle on right (or so I think)
3. I also removed a tiny component which appeared to be a resistor (left blue circle)
4. Put it back together. Insert battery
5. Had an adhesive backed foil laying around. Covered the led and some part of the back.
6. Done

Result = Distance between power-supply/receiver and remote now have to be 2-3 feet for it to work.

[image: Remote-1]
[image: Remote-2]
[image: Remote-3]
[image: Remote-4]
[image: Remote-5]